# What is the difference between these two functions involving typeof

Tags: javascript, html, typeof, template-strings

My teacher in JavaScript gave me an assignment to master functions. I tried to solve the assignment which requires me to make the output like the second code:

```
function showDetails(name = "unknown", age = "unknown", booleanez = "unknown") {
  let name22ez,num22ez,bool22ez;

  typeof booleanez === 'boolean'
    ? (bool22ez = booleanez)
    : typeof booleanez === "number"
    ? (bool22ez = age)
    : (bool22ez = name);

  typeof name === "string"
    ? (name22ez = name)
    : typeof name === "number"
    ? (name22ez = age)
    : (name22ez = booleanez);

  typeof age === "number"
    ? (num22ez = age)
    : typeof age === "string"
    ? (num22ez = name)
    : (num22ez = booleanez);
  return `Hello ${name22ez}, Your Age Is ${num22ez}, You ${
    bool22ez === true ? bool22ez =`Are` : bool22ez = `Are Not`
  } Available For Hire`;
}

document.write(showDetails("Osama", 38, true));
document.write(`<hr>`);
document.write(showDetails(38, "Osama", true));
document.write(`<hr>`);
document.write(showDetails(true, 38, "Osama"));
document.write(`<hr>`);
document.write(showDetails(false, "Osama", 38));
```

The Output Was:

```
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire
Hello 38, Your Age Is false, You Are Available For Hire
```

I tried so many times, for like 4 hours, to fix it, but I didn't so, I took the answer from another student and his answer was this:

```
function checkStatus(a, b, c) {
    let str, num, bool;
    typeof a === "string"
        ? (str = a)
        : typeof b === "string"
        ? (str = b)
        : (str = c);
    typeof a === "number"
        ? (num = a)
        : typeof b === "number"
        ? (num = b)
        : (num = c);
    typeof a === "boolean"
        ? (bool = a)
        : typeof b === "boolean"
        ? (bool = b)
        : (bool = c);
    return `Hello ${str}, Your Age Is ${num}, You ${
        bool ? "Are" : "Are Not"
    } Available For Hire`;
}

document.write(checkStatus("Osama", 38, true));
document.write(checkStatus(38, "Osama", true));
document.write(checkStatus(true, 38, "Osama"));
document.write(checkStatus(false, "Osama", 38));
```

The output was correct:

```
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire 
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire 
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Available For Hire 
Hello Osama, Your Age Is 38, You Are Not Available For Hire
```

What's the difference between mine and my fellow's code?

Comment: Why all the unnecessary type checking? Just pass an object to the function with `name`, `age`, and `forHire` attributes and stop the madness.

Comment: Your logic makes absolutely no sense. You're checking the type of `name`, then using `age` as the value to assign to the variable.

Comment: @J.Titus It's an assignment, he's supposed to duplicate the way the original function deals with arguments in different orders. He doesn't get to change the function signature.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that, but it's completely stupid. Nobody in their right mind would write code like this.

Comment: Don't use nested ternaries, they're very confusing. Maybe if you used `if` statements you would have gotten it right.

Comment: @J.Titus jQuery has lots of functions that work similar to this. They allow you to skip arguments or pass them in different order, figuring it out based on the different datatypes. Look at `$.post()`, for instance.

Comment: He Requried me also to use Ternary if condition

Comment: So if `name` is a number, why are you assigning `name22ez = age`?

Comment: You need to assign whichever parameter is a string to `name2ez`.

Comment: @J.Titus i didn't understand you could you explain more ?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, in version 1.0. Then they eventually got smarter and used a settings object.

Comment: @Barmar sorry but could you answer because i can't get tottaly understand with a theoretical information

Comment: @J.Titus if it completely stupid could you do it with a smarter way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code checks the type of each parameter. The parameter whose type is `string` is used as the name, the parameter whose type is number is used as the age, and the parameter whose type is boolean is used as the availability for hire.

Your conditional logic is totally mystifying to me. The first test in each ternary is correct -- if `booleanez` is boolean then it should be used for `bool22ez`. But the rest make no sense. If `booleanez` is a number, why does that mean that the `age` parameter should be assigned to `bool2ez`?

You need to use the same logic as the original, testing each parameter for a particular type, then using that as the value to assign to the variable that requires that type.

```
  typeof booleanez === 'boolean'
    ? (bool22ez = booleanez)
    : typeof age === "boolean"
    ? (bool22ez = age)
    : (bool22ez = name);
```

And since you're assigning the same variable, you should use the ternary just in the value part of the assignment rather than repeating the variable to assign to.

```
bool22ez = 
    typeof booleanez === 'boolean'
        ? booleanez
        : typeof age === "boolean"
        ? age
        : name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965243/17242583), this is the correct code:

```
function showDetails(name = "unknown", age = "unknown", booleanez = "unknown") {
  let name22ez,num22ez,bool22ez;

  typeof name === "string"
    ? (name22ez = name)
    : typeof age === "string"
    ? (name22ez = age)
    : (name22ez = booleanez);
  typeof age === "number"
    ? (num22ez = age)
    : typeof name === "number"
    ? (num22ez = name)
    : (num22ez = booleanez);
  typeof booleanez === 'boolean'
    ? (bool22ez = booleanez)
    : typeof name === "boolean"
    ? (bool22ez = name)
    : (bool22ez = age);
  return `Hello ${name22ez}, Your Age Is ${num22ez}, You ${
    bool22ez === true ? bool22ez =`Are` : bool22ez = `Are Not`
  } Available For Hire`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to derail the comment section of your post. My point is, a more sensible way to write this function would be something along the lines of:

```js
function showDetails(details) {
  // do some type checking up here for the existence of the values
  // because JavaScript is not a strongly typed language
  // ...
  // return the result if the details are provided
  return `Hello ${details.name}, Your Age Is ${details.age}, You ${details.forHire ? 'Are' : 'Are Not'} Available For Hire`;
}

console.log(showDetails({
  name: 'Osama',
  age: 38,
  forHire: true
}))

console.log(showDetails({
  name: 'Osama',
  age: 38,
  forHire: false
}))
```

Specifically for your assignment, though, listen to @Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I strongly agree with Barmar when he says *It's completely stupid. Nobody in their right mind would write code like this.*, I just **love** those challenges.

Have a look at the solution I would suggest if I were you:

```js
function showDetails(name = "unknown", age = "unknown", booleanez = "unknown") {
  
  // Accept specific types and one of each
  let acceptedTypes = ["string", "number", "boolean"];
  let typeSet = Array.from(new Set([typeof name, typeof age, typeof booleanez]));
  if (typeSet.length != 3) {
    return "ERROR - I need 3 different types of argument.";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < typeSet.length; i++) {
    if (acceptedTypes.indexOf(typeSet[i]) == -1) {
      return "ERROR - At least one argument is not accepted.";
    }
  }
  
  // Beyond this point, proceed!
  let args = [
    { type: typeof name, value: name },
    { type: typeof age, value: age },
    { type: typeof booleanez, value: booleanez }
  ];

  // Expecting in this order: "string", "number", "boolean"
  // which are in the reversed alphabetical order...
  // So use sort b-a on the types ;)
  args.sort((a, b) => b.type.localeCompare(a.type))

  return `Hello ${args[0].value}, Your Age Is ${args[1].value}, You Are ${args[2].value ? `` : `Not `}Available For Hire`;
}

console.log(showDetails("Osama", 38, true));
console.log(showDetails(38, "Osama", true));
console.log(showDetails(true, 38, "Osama"));
console.log(showDetails(false, "Osama", 38));
console.log(showDetails(0, "Osama", 38));
console.log(showDetails(0, "Osama", { age: 38 }));
console.log(showDetails());
```